# Как отличить текст в файле с обычной кодировкой от Unicode?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, текст

Нужно прочесть текстовый файл. Как узнать, закодирован таблицей символов (однобайтовых), или в файле содержится текст в формате Unicode (16-ти битные символы)?

Answer (score 8):

Файл всегда содержит байты. Иногда содержимое файла можно декодировать в текст, используя выбранную кодировку такую как cp1251, cp866, utf-8,  или utf-16le.

На Windows, файлы, закодированные в utf-16, к сожалению иногда называют Unicode (что вводит в заблуждение: [Unicode—это не кодировка](http://unicode.org/standard/WhatIsUnicode.html)). utf-16 это всего лишь одна из многих кодировок, которую можно использовать, чтобы закодировать текст ([Unicode](http://unicode.org/standard/WhatIsUnicode.html)) в байты:

```
байты = юникод_текст.encode(кодировка)
юникод_текст = байты.decode(кодировка)
```

Файлы, содержащие текст, закодированный в utf-8, utf-16, utf-32 и других кодировках, могут содержать в начале специальную последовательность байт (U+FEFF символ [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), закодированный в соответствующей кодировке), которая идентифицирует эти кодировки.

Если файл следует этому соглашению, то достаточно несколько первых байт из файла (в двоичном режиме открытого) сравнить с вариантами BOM, чтобы определить соответствующую кодировку. В общем случае нет гарантированного на 100% способа определить кодировку файла (хотя некоторые кодировки могут быть более вероятны чем другие и может быть API, которое пытается *угадать* кодировку, такое как: [`IsTextUnicode()` с `IS_TEXT_UNICODE_STATISTICS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318672(v=vs.85).aspx)). Пример: ["Bush hid the facts" текст](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts), закодированный в ascii кодировке, мог некоторыми приложениями интерпретироваться как текст в utf-16le кодировке, приводя к [кракозябрам](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Answer (score 5):

Зависит от соглашения, в котором записан текстовый файл. Текстовый поток, записанный в формате Unicode может начитаться с BOM - [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), т.е. например с магических байтов `FF`, `FE` для UTF-16 Little Endian.

А в отсутствие каких-либо соглашений - только анализ текста с элементами гадания на кофейной гуще.

Answer (score 2):

Простая на первый взгляд задача, но выполнить её оказывается не просто. `С++` обладает достаточной гибкостью, как язык среднего уровня, поэтому требуется исчерпывающее знание вопроса для эффективной реализации задачи. Поделюсь тем что выяснил.

Чтобы правильно прочесть файл нужно сначала посмотреть, есть ли в начале файла [Маркер последовательности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2&vesection=0) ([тут](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) точнее). Если есть маркер, его нужно определить. Если маркера нет, как выше уже было сказано, нужно искать другой алгоритм определения кодировки.

Я тут целиком и полностью полагаюсь на [`IsTextUnicode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318672(v=vs.85).aspx), если маркера нет:

```
BYTE *pBuf;
size_t szRead, szBOM; // к-во прочитанных в файле байт и к-во байт маркера
enum Unicode eUnicode;
LPTSTR pszText;
...
// определяю, есть ли в тексте маркер (ручная работа)
szBOM = IsUnicodeRaw(pBuf, szRead, &eUnicode);
// вызов библиотечной ф-ции IsTextUnicode после собственной проверки
if(eUnicode != utf_16LE && ((szRead - szBOM) % 2 || !IsTextUnicode(pBuf + szBOM, (int) (szRead - szBOM), NULL)))
{
    BYTE *pb = new BYTE[(szRead - szBOM + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)];
    unsigned int nCP = (eUnicode == utf_8) ? CP_UTF8 : (eUnicode == utf_7) ? CP_UTF7 : CP_ACP;
    if (!MultiByteToWideChar(nCP, (nCP == CP_ACP) ? MB_PRECOMPOSED : 0, (LPCSTR) (pBuf + szBOM), (int) (szRead - szBOM), (LPWSTR) pb, (int) (szRead - szBOM)))
    {
        // ошибка...
    }
    delete[] pBuf;
    pszText = (LPTSTR) (pszBuf = pb)
}
else
    pszText = (LPTSTR) (pszBuf + szBOM);
```

После того как выяснил наличие маркера в ф-ции `IsUnicodeRaw`, обращаюсь к [`IsTextUnicode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318672(v=vs.85).aspx) без маркера. Работает с `UTF-8`, с `UTF-7` нужно разбираться - там последние 2 бита маркера являются частью следующего за маркером символа. `ANSI`-текст так же нормально кодирует в двухбайтовый.

Wind'а предпочитает `UTF-8` и `UTF-16LE`. Перед тем как записать текст, его нужно либо перекодировать в `ANSI` ф-цией [`WideCharToMultibyte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx), либо в начало файла записать маркер кодировки `UTF-8` или `UTF-16LE`, чтобы потом также прочесть.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, нашёл. Ф-ция IsTextUnicode из Advapi32.dll ответит на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: Только нужно быть осторожным с этой функцией. Иногда она сильно ошибается. Стандартный блокнот также ее использует. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040324-00/?p=40093

Comment: Очень надеюсь, что вы всё-таки прочитали и поняли ответ jfs. )